# Euler-Lagrange equation (equation of motion) solution with hairy Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action

I'm going through Zwiebach Chapter 6 on relativistic strings to try to solve a
similar problem. I got all the way to my equation of motion

\begin{eqnarray*}
  \delta S & = & [ p' \delta \theta]_{z 0}^{z 1} + \int_{z 0}^{z 1} d z \left(
  p - \frac{\partial ( p')}{\partial z} \right) \delta \theta\\
  &  & \\
  \Longrightarrow p - \frac{\partial ( p')}{\partial z} & = & 0\\
  &  & \\
  {where} : &  & \\
  p & = & \frac{\partial L ( z, \theta, \theta')}{\partial \theta}\\
  p' & = & \frac{\partial L ( z, \theta, \theta')}{\partial \theta'}
\end{eqnarray*}
The Lagrangian I have is $\begin{array}{lll}
  L ( z, \theta, \theta') & = & \frac{\cos^3 \theta}{z^5} \sqrt{1 + z^2
  \theta'^2}
\end{array}$, and I know that this equation is the Euler Lagrange equation.

\begin{eqnarray*}
  \frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} - \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \left(
  \frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta'} \right) & = & 0\\
  &  & \\
  {where} : &  & \\
  \theta' ( z) & = & \frac{\partial \theta ( z)}{\partial z}\\
  L ( z, \theta, \theta') & = & \frac{\cos^3 \theta}{z^5} \sqrt{1 + z^2
  \theta'^2}
\end{eqnarray*}
Just putting the expression for $L$ into the equation gives me a mess \begin{array}{lll}
     \frac{- 3 \sin \theta \cos^2 \theta}{z^5} \sqrt{1 + z^2 \theta'^2} -
     \frac{\sqrt{2} \theta'' ( 2 \theta'^2 z^2 + 3) \cos^3 \theta}{z^4 (
     \theta'^2 z^2 + 2)^{3 / 2}} & = & 0
   \end{array} 
I don't think I'm supposed to brute force this. I know the solution to be
$\theta = \arcsin ( z)$, but I can't see how to get it. I'm thinking that
there is something I'm missing about the equation of motion.

Comment: oh and here is the link to the same question on physicsforums https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/euler-lagrange-equation-eom-solutions-hairy-lagrangian.787814/

Comment: This question seems to have very little physical content; is it purely a question about the manipulations to solve your particular equation, or do you think there's something *physical* that's stopping you from getting it?

Comment: Which exercise in Zwiebach's book is this? Please provide context.